# getting all users from particular columns value in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below is the schema of "users" model

```
id | First_Name | Zip
1  | abc        | 10005
2  | xyz        | 10005
3  | mno        | 10005
4  | ijk        | 10006
```

And I have a text_field where I enter zip code i.e below:

```
<%= form_for :search, :url => { :action => :search} do |f| %>
<table>
      <tr>
         <td align="center">
            <h2 style="color:Black; font-size: x-large;">Specs</h2>               
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td align="center">
                  <%= f.text_field :tf_Zip,placeholder: "Zip" %>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <div class="button">

                    <%= f.submit "Search", { :class => "buttonSearch"} %>

                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

And  I want to get all users whose "Zip == 10005", and I am using below code:

```
  def search
    if ( !params[:search][:tf_Zip].blank? or params[:search][:tf_Zip] !="" )
   @user_zip = User.where(user_Zip: params[:search][:tf_zip])
end     
render 'search'
  end
```

but its not working fine, Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: i see also a typo: the exception says that you're looking for an empty id, in fact you're passing to your find (to substitute with where clause as others said)  the params[:tf_zip] whereas you're passing params[:tf_Zip] from your form (same checking with the if statement). HAve you checked it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use `.where`:

```
 def search
    if ( !params[:tf_Zip].blank? or params[:tf_Zip] !="" )
        @user_zip = User.where(zip: params[:tf_zip])
    end     
    render 'search'
  end
```

Comment: Little bit more info will help? You've received the exact same answer from someone else -- it's the right way to do it

Comment: what do you want to do here: zip: params[:tf_zip]

Comment: Perform a `where` query using those params

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with the following code.

```
def search
 @user_zip = params[:search][:tf_Zip].blank? ? [] : User.where(zip: params[:search][:tf_Zip])
 render 'search'
end
```

Comment: It give me error "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def search
  @user_zip = User.where(zip: params[:tf_Zip]) if params[:tf_Zip].any?
end
```

You must check `params` parameters. I don't sure it will be `params[:search][:tf_Zip]` but you should recheck and write right as you have it in app.